# Custom sortable dropdown for JQuery datatable column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have added dropdown selection in jQuery datatable.

```
table.columns().every(function() {
    var column = this;
    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
      .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
      .on('change', function() {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );
        column
          .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });
    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(value, j) {
      select.append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>')
    });
  });
```

following is full source code
[plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ly8cq96TouPYUSNbeFCh?p=preview).

When I open dropdown values are sorted as String not as integer.
For example here dropdowns gives selection

```
[1,10,11,2,...] && [Item 1,Item 10,Item 11,...]
```

I want answer as

```
[1,2,3,4,..10,11..] && [Item 1,Item 2,Item 3,...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [Sorting plugins](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/)

Modify your code like this:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
            { "type": "natural", targets: 0 },
            { "type": "natural", targets: 1 }
    ]
});
```

The result can be seen here: https://plnkr.co/edit/MJgKWrYpFmmr0v43hKd4?p=preview